# How to combine similar named files from multiple folders into one folder for each file name

Tags: python, command-line, copy

I have 400 folders. Within each folder, there are 3 additional folders I have to drill into and then in the last folder I have 22 different files. Each of these 400 folders have the same named files. Ultimately, I want to create 22 folders, one for each file name and within each of the 22 folders I want only files that have the same name. Since a folder cannot have two files with the same name, adding the final 6 characters of the file path to the file name solves the issue.

Using the image below as an example of the files:

```
I need an ACO folder with 400 files all of which are labeled i.e., "ACO050168", "ACO150074", "ACO150128"
I need an BDUAL folder with 400 files all of which are labeled BDUAL i.e., "BDUAL050168", "BDUAL150074", "BDUAL150128"
etc..
```

Here are file paths for example, notice that the final folder and the 4th from the last folder are unique

```
 'C:\\Users\\MBobak\\Documents\\Loop\\Raw Claims Data 050168\\D#CJR\\Y2018M02\\P050168',
 'C:\\Users\\MBobak\\Documents\\Loop\\Raw Claims Data 150074\\D#CJR\\Y2018M02\\P150074',
 'C:\\Users\\MBobak\\Documents\\Loop\\Raw Claims Data 150128\\D#CJR\\Y2018M02\\P150128'
```

The 22 files within each folder are structured as `.csv` but do not have the `.csv` extension. They are just `files`. I attached an image to show what it looks like. [image]

I know there are ways to do this in the command-line, but I can't find a specific example of this question since there are drills downs from each initial folder.

I attempted to do this in python, and I wrote a small script in python to find the final directories that hold the 22 files:

```
all_files_dir = r'C:\Users\MBobak\Documents\Loop'

folders = os.listdir(all_files_dir)
ccn_list = [x[-6:] for x in folders]

ccn_file_dir = [r'C:\Users\MBobak\Documents\Loop\Raw Claims Data ' + x + '\D#CJR\Y2018M02\P' + x for x in ccn_list]
```

But now I am having trouble copying/moving these into new folders.

Comment: Should the ACO folder have files named "ACO050168", "ACO150074", "ACO150128", etc ? Or,... what should they be named?

Comment: I just realized that you cannot have the same name twice in a folder... Changing the names like you do is ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some helpful suggestions and intense googling, I came up with this below which does what I need. This script will go into each folder and rename each file as it copies it into another folder, which is titled the original file name. The final result has 22 folders (as described in the question) with 400 files each. The code below includes the snippet from the question stem.

```
import os, shutil

dest = r'C:\Users\MBobak\Documents\Target_Folder'
all_folders_dir = r'C:\Users\MBobak\Documents\Staging_Folder'
files_22 = r'C:\Users\MBobak\Documents\Staging_Folder\Raw Claims Data 050069\D#CJR\Y2018M02\P050069' ## pulling list of all the named files 

folders = os.listdir(all_folders_dir)
files = os.listdir(files_22)
ccn_list = [x[-6:] for x in folders]
ccn_file_dir = [r'C:\Users\MBobak\Documents\Raw Claims Data ' + x + '\D#CJR\Y2018M02\P' + x for x in ccn_list]

for file in files:
    for hosp_folder, ccn in zip(ccn_file_dir, ccn_list):
        if not os.path.exists(dest+'\\'+file):
            os.mkdir(dest+'\\'+file)
        shutil.copy(hosp_folder+"\\"+file ,dest +'\\'+ file +'\\'+ file + '_' + ccn)
```

Comment: * Good answer *

Answer (score 3):

So - not enough reputation to comment and ask for more info. To me it sounds like you have similar filenames in the bottom of the structure that you want copied to the same target folder?

Ie you want all ACO files to end up in a folder named ACO??? You can only have one file with that name in a folder.

So this first version will actually overwrite any similar named file in the target folder. Can you clarify what you really need? Ie an example of the target folder contents and filenames.

```
# folder.py
import os
import sys
import platform
import shutil

walk_dir = sys.argv[1]

if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    delimiter = '\\'
else:
    delimiter = '/'

print('walk_dir = ' + walk_dir)
print('walk_dir (absolute) = ' + os.path.abspath(walk_dir))

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(walk_dir):
    print('--\ncurrent = ' + root)

    for filename in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)

        print('\t- file %s (full path: %s)' % (filename, file_path))
        target_name = root[root.rfind(delimiter)+2:len(root)]
        if not os.path.isdir(filename):
            os.mkdir(filename)
        target = filename + delimiter + filename + target_name
        shutil.copy2(file_path,target)
```

Call it like this:

```
C:\\Users\\MBobak\\Documents\\python folder.py Loop
```

If you can give me more information I may be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks for the comments @cpaludan

Comment: My pleasure - see if the updated version doesn't work for you.

Comment: I am a little confused about this. 1. The last for loop doesn't have any subsequent lines indented. 2. From what I understand, I need to save as a `.py` and run this in `cmd` but I'm not sure where to explicitly call the path. I see you wrote `Loop` but when I attempted this I didn't get any response.

Comment: I am sorry about the indentation in the last for loop - that was my mistake when I updated the code. Except for the more specific destination you did below, this code does what you need. It will create the 22 folders  in the same folder as you are running the script from.